# Bearing angle and distance between heading and target point

Tags: arduino, bearing

I'd like to calculate the bearing angle and the distance between heading point and target point  with three coordinates for an arduino navigation.

coordinates system looks something like this.
[image]

(x1, y1) = heading point, (x3, y3) = target point

Any help here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calculation methods can be found at [this site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Notice that for distance you can have Haversine calculation (less precise) or Vincent calculation (excelent precision - check the formula [here](https://github.com/janantala/GPS-distance/blob/master/java/Distance.java))

I'm using these formulas with GoogleMaps API and works pretty good.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but my coordinates are Cartesian, not (lat, long). In that case, do I need to convert them to (lat, lon)? if yes how? I am getting confused here.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert them. I'm not sure how you can convert it, but If you make some search I'm quite sure you will find a way. This kind of conversion is quite commom.